# Google Script: SetTitle to existing title + Add text or emojie

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

How do I append more text the calendar title name with Google Apps Scripts.

I have made a function to search for and change settings/class for specific calendar items - it works.

However, I would very much like to **update the calendar title** - so the final title is set to (appending text + original titel).

- **Exampel:**
- [Original title: Question from client about price]
- [Append text: ❓]
- [Final calendar title setTitle: ❓ Question from client about price]

  ```
        events.forEach((event)=>{
            Logger.log(event.getTitle());
            event.setColor("8");
            event.setTag('Spørgsmål' , 'spg');
   ------>  Need help here: event.setTitle(); <------

      })
  ```

Is this somehow doable?

Best regards,
Casper

Comment: Just add them using `+`: `event.setTitle(""+event.getTitle())`

Comment: Many thanks TheMaster! works very fine.